# Query docker postgres from docker flask

Tags: postgresql, flask, docker-compose

I'm studying the world of dockers, I got to the point where I want to query postgres table from flask app. So I created the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  pg_data_wh:
    container_name: pg_data_wh
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my_data_wh_db
      POSTGRES_USER: my_data_wh_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_data_wh_pwd
    ports:
      - "5488:5432"
    volumes:
      - pg_data_wh:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pg_grafana:
    container_name: pg_grafana
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my_grafana_db
      POSTGRES_USER: my_grafana_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_grafana_pwd
    ports:
      - "5499:5432"
    volumes:
      - pg_grafana:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    user: "0:0"
    environment:
      GF_DATABASE_TYPE: postgres
      GF_DATABASE_HOST: pg_grafana:5432
      GF_DATABASE_NAME: my_grafana_db
      GF_DATABASE_USER: my_grafana_user
      GF_DATABASE_PASSWORD: my_grafana_pwd
      GF_DATABASE_SSL_MODE: disable
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
        - pg_grafana
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3000"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
         
    ports:
      - 3111:3000
    volumes:
      - grafana:/var/lib/grafana
      - ../flask/custom_config/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini:ro
  flask_app:
    build:
      context: ../flask
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: flask_app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - grafana
    volumes:
      - C:\Alon\New\flask-grafana-postgres\flask:/app:rw



volumes:
  pg_grafana:
    driver: local
  grafana:
    driver: local
  pg_data_wh:
    driver: local
```

The app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from routes.routes import main_routes
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()


app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(main_routes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

The Grafana doesn't really matter right now.

So for testing the connection, I'm trying to get a return for the postgres version, with two funcs.
The first:

```
def get_postgres_cursor():
    connection = None
    cursor = None
    
    

    try:
        # Replace these with your actual database connection details
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
            user=database_user,
            password=database_password,
            host=database_host,
            port=database_port,
            database=database_name
        )

        cursor = connection.cursor()

        return cursor, connection

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if connection:
            connection.close()
```

The second:

```
def get_postgres_version(cursor):
    try:
        # Execute a simple query to get the PostgreSQL version
        cursor.execute("SELECT version();")

        # Fetch the result
        postgres_version = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print(f"PostgreSQL version: {postgres_version}")

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Error while executing query", error)

    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
```

And the end point itself:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify, render_template
import psycopg2
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from db_funcs import get_postgres_cursor,get_postgres_version

load_dotenv()


main_routes = Blueprint('app',__name__)

@main_routes.route('/dash')
def index():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')


@main_routes.route('/connect_postgres')
def get_postgres_version():
    try:
        cursor, connection = get_postgres_cursor()
        version_info = get_postgres_version(cursor)
        print(version_info)
        return version_info
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
    return version_info
```

I play around with the structure of the funcs and I kinda got lost, but no matter what I do I either get this error:
[image]

And another I got a lot was this:

[image]

Now the question is this -
How do I set up a connection where I can query postgres from flask app? In this example it's just for the version, but I'll want to query real data from the app, so if there any nuances I should know.

Any tips and tricks for dealing with these scenarios in general would be more than welcome too.

Thanks!

Comment: try `host=pg_data_wh` and `port=5432` instead of `localhost` and `5488`?

Comment: Well - I did try it before asking here, but your comment made me see i had a typo in the connection string i didn't notice before. Anyhow - thanks, it works!